# CSS - Make text wrap over image

Tags: css

I just stuck dealing with image positioning and text-wrapping above (!) it. Situation is simple: I have 'p' element with some text and 'img' inside this 'p', all I need is: move down my image inside this paragraph and make text wrap this over image.

```
<p><img src="/some/source/">Some text</p>
```

[Here is codepen representation of my problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJjbRW)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Plese have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the four numbers after margin represent TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT. So if you want to add the whitespace to a right-aligned image, you would do this:

```
<img data-original="IMAGE URL" align="right" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;" /><p>Your text goes here.</p>
```

Also check [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds4p6.html) tutorial

> Align attribute Values

`<img align="left|right|middle|top|bottom">`

Comment: it doesn't work because margin-top takes space above image, and blocks text to enter this space

Comment: still does not work, to achieve my goal i need to insert image inside text, i mean not from beginning, but problem is: i cannot manipulate DOM, so i'll stick with JS then

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shape-outside property to create a shape around the image and wrap the text like:

```
shape-outside:polygon(20px 280px, 260px 29px,9px 215px,30px 80px)
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjpYrV)**